# GitKraken: Clone 0%

Tags: git, gitkraken

I connected my GitLab (self-hosted) account and try to clone repo, but the progress of cloning is always 0%.

[image]

Could this be due to the fact that the repo is large enough? 3.3 gigabytes,

Comment: Is it actually at 0%, or is your computer working hard to download that 3.3 GB and GitKraken can't keep up? Look in the directory 'AR Mumi' where the clone is supposed to be happening. Is there a directory there with the same name as your project, that's getting bigger?

Comment: Only .git folder created in the AR Mumi directory, after start cloning and nothing else. Internet connection is good and I left the download for an hour, but nothing has changed.